# Kill system process in Thread ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

How I can kill ping (or other VERY LONGEST without timeout and etc system process)(ping -  it's  just simple example) in ruby Thread:

```
a = Thread.new do
    system 'ping localhost'
end

a.kill
a.exit
a.terminate

while true
    sleep 5
    p a.alive?
end
```

Output:=>

```
PING localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.023 ms
....
true
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=7 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms
.....
true
......
```

So I need stop ping process with Thread, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can take a look into the GEM [God](http://godrb.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) does not give you `pid`.

Use [`Process::spawn`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Process.html#method-c-spawn) instead. And use [`Process::kill`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Process.html#method-c-kill) to kill the process using the pid returned by `Process::spawn`.

For example:

```
pid = Process.spawn('ping localhost')
sleep 3
Process.kill(:TERM, pid)
Process.wait(pid)
```